# Requestmap option is not showing in navigation bar

Tags: grails

I am unable to show 'requestmap' option in navigation bar. I did a few google searches but couldn't fix the problem. I and using grails 2.5.1 & dependency plugins are:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pgFv.png)

```
compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC5"
compile ":spring-security-ui:1.0-RC2"
```

I have created domain classes by running command `s2-quickstart com.domain.pack User Role Requestmap`.

I tried few options like placing these two lines in confi.groovy file as per documentation.

```
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.SecurityConfigType
grails.plugin.springsecurity.securityConfigType = SecurityConfigType.Requestmap
```

But when I run the app it redirects me `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` in browser. then I tried with option:

`springSecurityService.clearCachedRequestmaps()` in my Bootstrap.groovy file but all in vain. I am stuck, any help will be appriciated.
Thanks.

```
def init = { servletContext ->
    User testuser = new User(username:'admin', password:'secret', enabled:true).save()
    Role  admin = new Role(authority: 'ROLE_ADMIN').save();

    UserRole.create(testuser, admin)

    if (!Requestmap.count()) {
    for (String url in [
            '/screen/index', '/index', '/index.gsp', '/**/favicon.ico',
            '/assets/**', '/**/js/**', '/**/css/**', '/**/images/**',
            '/login', '/login.*', '/login/*',
            '/logout', '/logout.*', '/logout/*']) {
        new Requestmap(url: url, configAttribute: 'permitAll').save()
    }
        new Requestmap(url: '/screen/*', configAttribute: 'ROLE_ADMIN').save()

   }
    springSecurityService.clearCachedRequestmaps()

}
def destroy = {
}
```

}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsRCe.png)

Comment: You will need to enable spring security debugging and figure out why it is redirecting - I don't think anyone from this end not with your app config besides configuring it will be able to give you much advice on `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` since that is too generic and will reside in your config. incidentally `'/screen/index' permitAll` and '/screen/*'  'ROLE_ADMIN'` do you think this could be why ?

Comment: sorry for confusion, I had more lines of code, for simplicity, I just removed few of them. Also I have many controllers like 'screen' above. as per now I have commented line    "new Requestmap(url: url, configAttribute: 'permitAll').save()" but it takes me to the login page but it is not recognizing me.. it says "Sorry, you're not authorized to view this page." But my point is although User , Roles , Registration Code and Security code are visible in my navigation bar by default why Requestmaps option is not vsibile. should I have to use any dependency plugin for it or something ?

Comment: please refer to comment 1 enable debugging which will be very verbose but will point you in the right direction of what is causing the you are not authorised maybe you haven;t configured application.groovy correctly to point at right place - too many reasons to give you any specific answer on this

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue. Adding this code in `Bootsrap.groovy` fixed it for me .

```
new Requestmap(url: '/logout/**', configAttribute: 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED,IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY').save();
new Requestmap(url: '/login/**', configAttribute: 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY').save()
new Requestmap(url: '/index/**', configAttribute: 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY').save();
```

Hope it works for you too.